# Display database entries categorised

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

I've build a web app around TV Shows to study AngularJS. So, I have a database table filled with TV Shows with a column `category`. So for example `Dexter` will have a category `thriller`. How can I display these by category?

This is the controller fetching them from the database:

```
$http.get('/all').success(function(data) {

    $scope.allshows = data; 

});
```

And this is the view displaying them:

```
<ul>

    <li ng-repeat="show in allshows">

        <h1>{{ show.name }}</h1>

    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it (angular 1.2)

```
<li ng-repeat="show in allshows | filter:{'category':'thriller'}">
```

Comment: I figured it out on my own, but this is exactly how I did it!